# How to POST Request with multiple objects in Python

Tags: python, post, https, python-requests

I'm able to use the post method with any url but this one, when I use postman to send the same request (same body, key, etc) the request works absolutely fine!, However when I use python (with requests library) it simply wont work, I used the following code:

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://app.funildevendas.com.br/api/opportunity?&IntegrationKey=(cant give it up, but it's defintely right)"
payload =  {
     "oportunidades": [

     {
     "titulo": "TestePython",
     "valor": 10440,
     "codigo_vendedor": 38171,
     "codigo_metodologia": 1,
     "codigo_etapa": 2,
     "codigo_canal_venda":69400,

     "empresa": {
     "nome": "Python",
     "cnpj": "",
     "ie": "",
     "segmento": "",
     "endereco_completo": {
     "logradouro": "",
     "numero": "",
     "complemento": "",
     "bairro": "",
     "cidade": "",
     "uf": "",
     "cep": ""
     }

     },
     "contato": {
     "nome": "Nome do contato",
     "email": "email@contato.com.br",
     "telefone1": "",
     "telefone2": "",
     "cargo": "",
     "cpf": ""
     }

     }
     ]
    }
res = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload))
```

I do get the response [200] but it doesn't seem to recognize the body structure.
The response I get is:

```
{"response":"failure","message":"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference","value":null}
```

I wonder if it is because of the "[" right before "oportunidades" but changing it to "{" result in a syntax error. My integration key is definetely right, so is my body (payload) since both work just fine using postman

Comment: it may look like there's a mistake in url however It's just because I accidentally closed " ' " when censoring sensitive info

Comment: Thank you for editing, I'm still new to stack overflow and couldn't find how to do it.
Regarding the problem: I think it's something in my code since the postman request works just fine with the exact same info.
Thank you so much for your reply though.
I'm not sending content-type: application.json because I didn't really had to in other requests that used this content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `data=json.dumps(payload)` to `json=payload`

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://app.funildevendas.com.br/api/opportunity?&IntegrationKey=(cant give it up, but it's defintely right)"
payload =  {
     "oportunidades": [

     {
     "titulo": "TestePython",
     "valor": 10440,
     "codigo_vendedor": 38171,
     "codigo_metodologia": 1,
     "codigo_etapa": 2,
     "codigo_canal_venda":69400,

     "empresa": {
     "nome": "Python",
     "cnpj": "",
     "ie": "",
     "segmento": "",
     "endereco_completo": {
     "logradouro": "",
     "numero": "",
     "complemento": "",
     "bairro": "",
     "cidade": "",
     "uf": "",
     "cep": ""
     }

     },
     "contato": {
     "nome": "Nome do contato",
     "email": "email@contato.com.br",
     "telefone1": "",
     "telefone2": "",
     "cargo": "",
     "cpf": ""
     }

     }
     ]
    }
res = requests.post(url,json=payload)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!! It worked!!!!! I've been trying to do this thing for the last 3 hours

Comment: Glad I could help :)